# Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Error on creating a new plan on a connected account

Tags: node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe v7.6.0 with typescript node app. I'm trying to create a new plan (for a subscription) on a connected account. Here's my snippet:

```
  const stripeAccount = "acct_2Gk346Btfer3fzH9";
  plan = await this.stripe.plans.create({
    amount,
    currency,
    interval,
    product: {
      name: productName,
    },
  }, { stripeAccount });
```

[Github says](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node):

> A per-request Stripe-Account header for use with Stripe Connect can be
>   added to any method:
>
> ```
> // List the balance transactions for a connected account:
> stripe.balanceTransactions.list(
>   {
>     limit: 10,
>   },
>   {
>     stripeAccount: 'acct_foo',
>   }
> );
> ```

[Stripe-node wiki](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options):

> All methods can accept an optional options object containing one or
>   more of the following:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> stripe.charges.refund(chargeId, {
>   amount: 500,
> }, {
>    stripeAccount: connectedAccountId,
> });
> ```

Based on the links above, I assume my code should work fine. But I get an error:

> (node:9737) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Stripe: Unknown
>   arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object?
>   See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options. (on
>   API request to POST `/plans`)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you share the values for  amount, currency, interval, and productName? If those are all strings, and assuming this.stripe is an instance of the Stripe object, this code should work. I have a feeling one of those is an object not a string.

Comment: @w1zeman1p I'm using typescript, so there's a lot of type checking along the way and pull those values with enums and getters. And I tried tried hardcoding all values directly. Still thanks a lot for your suggestion. I spent a few hours on this and I just found an answer. See my post if interested.

Answer (score 4):

This is huge. **Snake case instead of camelCase**.

Working example:

```
  plan = await this.stripe.plans.create({
    amount,
    currency,
    interval,
    product: {
      name: productName,
    },
  }, { stripe_account: stripeAccount });
```

Comment: This saved me hours!

Comment: Stripe: 'api_key' is deprecated; use 'apiKey' instead.